# Vue.js router isn't working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've looked at the various other questions on Stackoverflow regarding routes not working, and none of them point to why my routes aren't working.

Here is my router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Foo from '@/components/Forms/foo'
import Bar from '@/components/Forms/bar'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo
    },
    {
      path: '/bar',
      component: Bar
    }
  ]
})
```

**Here foo:**

```
<template id="foo">
    <form name="basic-form" v-on:submit="submit">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input v-model="firstName" name="first-name" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'foo',
  data: function () {
    return {
      firstName
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit: function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.$data.firstName)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here is bar:**

```
<template id="createDb">
    <button v-on:click="createDb">Create Database</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CreateDb'
}
</script>
```

It's worth noting that each of these components work on their own if I set the path to the root `/`. Essentially, no matter what is typed in - it navigates to the root and thus will grab and use any component that is associated with the root. I'm lost as to why this is.

Comment: Can you include the root component with `<router-view>`?

Answer (score 3):

I friend of mine gave me the answer on twitter, adding the `mode: 'history'` to the router makes it work as expected, here it is updated:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo
    },
    {
      path: '/bar',
      component: Bar
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I will - I gotta wait 2 days though :)

Comment: my life-saver :D